# Find the value of $3^{\log_4(5)} - 5^{\log_4(3)}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Find the value of $3^{\log_4(5)} - 5^{\log_4(3)}$.

Is there any property that can help here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the following rule on both powers: $$a^x=\left(4^{\log_4(a)}\right)^x=4^{\log_4(a)x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\log_45=x\implies4^x=5,\log_43=y\implies4^y=3$

$5^{\log_43}=(4^x)^y=4^{xy}$

and $3^{\log_45}=(4^y)^x=4^{xy}$

as $x,y$ are real

**See**  : [Power of Power](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power) Law

Answer (score 0):

$3^{\log_4 5}=(4^{\log_4 3})^{(\log_4 5)}=4^{(\log_4 3)(\log_4 5)}=4^{(\log_4 5)(\log_4 3)}=(4^{\log_4 5})^{(\log_4 3)}=5^{\log_4 3}.$..... By the same method, replacing $3,4,5$ with any positive values $a,b,c,$ with $b\ne 1$, we have $a^{\log_b c}=c^{\log_b a}.$